# iOS plugin for PhoneGap not called when click

Tags: plugins, cordova

I use an iOS plugin for PhoneGap, my plugin works fine when I call him directly, the problem is when I called my plugin at the click event

```
callNativePlugin('success');//Working fine



$(".Button").on('touchstart',function(){
      callNativePlugin('success');//Not working
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, in fact the problem was a simple javascript conflict that prevented the execution of the event click.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the ".Button" selector is matching an HTML element in the page?

i.e. does this work?

```
$(".Button").on('touchstart',function(){
  alert("touchstart worked");
  callNativePlugin('success');//Not working??
});
```